# How can I create Script file on Mac OS 10.4.8 to run example.exe file through mono?

Tags: macos, mono

I can open Terminal and write mono example.exe, but I want to double click any file,and it run
example.exe.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by *script*  is to change **file associations** then read [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/help/mac-change-program.html) and [here](http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/25/change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x/) and tell it to open *.exe files using mono and the filename as argument.

EDIT: I think what you did mean is [macpack](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#macpack_.28Mac_OS_X_only.29) and [here](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app)